# Transactional Replication and distribution database size

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, disk-space, datafile, filegroups

I have a transactional replication set up with initialize from backup.
In the secondary database server,i have a drive(d:) for data files alone.
I have noticed that this drive is getting filled and i see that distribution database is like 250 GB now.
What are steps to take to take care of this space issue.?
I know that adding additional disk space is one solution.But i have to keep the replication running till the new purchase order is done and the space is added.

Comment: This [Enhance Transactional Replication Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/enhance-transactional-replication-performance?view=sql-server-2017) should answer all your questions .